# How to share Views between ASP.NET vNext MVC 6 (beta1) projects?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC5 it was possible to share Views (Razor) between projects by using a tool like Razor Generator ( http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com ).
How to achieve the same in vNext? My Views aren't recognized out of the box (the project containing views is listed as a dependency in `project.json`).

`InvalidOperationException: The partial view '~/Views/Authentication/_LogInForm.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Authentication/_LogInForm.cshtml`

Comment: I should have mentioned it: including "RazorGenerator.Mvc" in the source project doesn't work anymore (the reference gets a "!" in front of it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We finally managed to solve this. Not quite easy though...

1. You need to embed the views as resources in the project you'll depend on. To do this, add `"resources": [ "**/*.cshtml" ]` to its project.json.
2. You need to create an IFileSystem that looks into those resources instead of looking on the disk. This is the tricky part. I put this on pastbin for lisibility: http://pastebin.com/aNfq5hNi
3. You need to register this IFileSystem in your Startup.cs:

`//...
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,IHostingEnvironment env,ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
    {
        //Enable use of views in other assemblies
        IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions> razorViewEngineOptions=app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>>();
        razorViewEngineOptions.Options.FileSystem=new MVCAsset.EmbeddedExpiringFileInfoCache(
            razorViewEngineOptions,
            app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILibraryManager>()
        );
        //...
    }
    //...`

NB : This is actually tested and working for MVC6 RC1, I didn't test for BETA1.

Comment: Have you updated this code to work on MVC6-beta4? Some of the code you posted doesn't work anymore due to breaking changes in the library.

Comment: Do you have a beta 5 version?

Comment: Anyone looked at this for the more recent beta's 6, 7 etc?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this helps accessing views in external assemblies, but to add locations where views can be discovered you can implement IViewLocationExpander like this:

```
public class ViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        var locations = new List<string>(viewLocations);

        locations.Add("Views/MyOtherViewLocation/{0}.cshtml");

        return locations;
    }

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

In your Startup.cs ConfigureServices method, add:

```
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {
            var expander = new ViewLocationExpander();
            options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(expander);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, even if it didn't answer the question. I posted a working answer to my own question above.

Comment: Yep, you can't use custom view locations outside web root using this solution.